# My "localhost" on a specific (Wordpress) folder send back localhost:8080 (which isn't exist)

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WAMP and have setup a Wordpress localy few months ago.
It's already online and works quiet well !
Today I wanted to redesign, reorganise code and up to date few elements on the home page.
I usually start my WAMP server on localhost and try to access my folder =>

"localhost/btf"

But Chrome load "localhost:8080/btf" which should be the localhost I used before, back when I created my wordpress the first time. I don't rememer why and how I changed "localhost" (alone) to "localhost:8080" on WAMP configuration, but I suppose something hasn't follow the URL change ONLY on "btf" project.

I already tried to edit "adress" in wordpress option (through PHPMyAdmin) but it changed nothing.
I already tried to restart computer & wamp.
I already tried to copy / paste the folder.
I already tried other folders (other projects) and it works correctly
I've searched in the entire "btf" folder, every wordpress elements with Sublime Text (search : 8080) and only sent me back hexadecimal colors (#080808).

I'm out of place to search. If there's any informations you need just ask.

Comment: Ok actually I succeed to have access to my folder "btf" using "Listen 8080" in my Apache httpd file. But why "localhost/btf" is loading EVERY TIME "localhost:8080/btf" ?

Comment: Hey, very good thing to read, thank you for this :)